# How do I stop /etc/resolv.conf being repeatedly reset to point to 192.168.33.2?

Tags: centos, dns, vmware-workstation

On a windows host, I have **two virtual guests on vmware workstation14**. I have configured two adapters `ens33` and `ens37` for those guests, NAT and host only respectively. The vnet adapter for NAT on the host is `192.168.33.1`  and vnet adapter for host-only is `192.168.220.1`. `ens33`'s IP series is `192.168.33.x` and `ens37`'s IP are in `192.168.220.x`.

My router is acting as the default DNS server for the host. Currently the gateway for my VMs is `192.168.33.2`. I am trying to configure a DNS server for the host-only network of VMs and have done so on VM1. However, while I was trying to configure the VM2 as a client to VM1 DNS server, it is repeatedly looking upto `192.168.33.2` and taking the name from it. I have edited the `/etc/resolv.conf` to add the IP of VM1 as the nameserver, yet no good. 
There is also I have seen. If i start my VM1 or VM2 the edit of `/etc/resolv.conf` reverts to `192.168.33.2`. Could anyone please help clarifying me on this?

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Don't lower the niveau, please write "I" in uppercase.

Comment: Can you complete your post with this data format: hostname - host ip; vm №1 name - vm №1 ip and network mode; vm №2 name - vm №2 ip and network mode; etc...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is setup by `dhclient` and then a process is constantly overwriting your `/etc/resolv.conf`; this is very non-UNIX-like.

What you can do, is configure dhcpclient NOT to retrieve `domain-name-servers`, you do this by editing `/etc/dhcpclient.conf`.

On the line starting with `request` you remove `domain-name-servers`. Then, of course, you restart the system (it is a VM, I assume no issues in that).